# Karaf 4.0.0 M2, Hibernate 4.3.6, and org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException

Tags: hibernate, karaf, aries

I am following the Karaf/Database tutorial by Christian Schneider at the following url:
http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access

My changes to this tutorial are to use MySql and Hibernate instead of H2 and OpenJpa.  With that said, I get my custom bundle to load, but Hibernate is unable to get use reflection to access attributes in my entity class.  The stack trace I am getting is below.

Some specific questions I have are:

1. Do I need a hibernate.properties file, as the persistence.xml file references the data source and allows for hibernate properties to be set
2. Are there additional dependencies I need in my pom.xml file
3. Is there some other reason not related to pom.xml or hibernate.properties which is causing the exception shown below?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Randy

```
2015-06-05 16:40:04,088 | ERROR | nsole user karaf | ShellUtil                        | 41 - org.apache.karaf.shell.core - 4.0.0.M2 | Exception caught while executing command
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.persist(Unknown Source)[146:org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context:1.0.4]
    at net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.impl.PersonServiceImpl.add(PersonServiceImpl.java:23)[167:leonard-orm-native:1.0.0]
    at Proxyead5dc4a_ed6c_46e9_8aad_e93af2278046.add(Unknown Source)[:]
    at net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.command.AddPersonCommand.execute(AddPersonCommand.java:42)[167:leonard-orm-native:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:34)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.compat.CommandTracker$1.execute(CommandTracker.java:109)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:267)[41:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0.M2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.transaction.impl.JTAEntityManagerHandler.invoke(JTAEntityManagerHandler.java:185)[146:org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context:1.0.4]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.persist(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerProxyFactory$EMHandler.invoke(EntityManagerProxyFactory.java:31)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.Person.name
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.Person.name
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.Person.name to net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.Person
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 38 more
```

---

blueprint.xml

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
        http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
        http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0 
        http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0 ">

<bean id="personService" class="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.impl.PersonServiceImpl">
    <jpa:context unitname="Leonard" property="entityManager" />
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
</bean>

<service ref="personService" interface="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.PersonService" />

<command-bundle xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/shell/v1.0.0">
    <command name="person/add">
        <action class="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.command.AddPersonCommand">
            <property name="personService" ref="personService" />
        </action>
    </command>
    <command name="person/list">
        <action class="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.command.ListPersonsCommand">
            <property name="personService" ref="personService" />
        </action>
    </command>
    <command name="person/deleteAll">
        <action class="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.command.DeleteAllPersonsCommand">
            <property name="personService" ref="personService" />
        </action>
    </command>
</command-bundle>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Leonard" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/Leonard</jta-data-source>
        <class>net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.Person</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Person.java

```
package net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String twitterName;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(String name, String twitterName)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.twitterName = twitterName;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "twitterName")
    public String getTwitterName()
    {
        return twitterName;
    }

    public void setTwitterName(String twitterName)
    {
        this.twitterName = twitterName;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.leonard.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>leonard-orm-native</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <properties>
        <log4j-version>1.2.16</log4j-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.console</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.apache.felix.service.command;version="[0.6,1)",
                            org.apache.felix.gogo.commands;version="[0.6,1)",
                            org.apache.karaf.shell.console;version="[2.2,4)",
                            *,
                            org.hibernate.jpa,
                            org.hibernate.proxy,
                            javassist.util.proxy
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
package net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.impl;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.Person;
import net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.PersonService;

public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService
{    
    private EntityManager em;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em)    
    {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public void add(Person person)
    {
        em.persist(person);
        em.flush();
    }

    public void deleteAll()
    {
        em.createQuery("delete from Person").executeUpdate();
        em.flush();
    }

    public List<Person> getAll()
    {
        return em.createQuery("select p from Person p", Person.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

---

I've re-started my karaf instance, and reviewed the logs from startup.  The following item has caught my attention:

```
2015-06-06 04:17:02,988 | WARN  | FelixStartLevel  | aries                            | 144 - org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint.aries - 1.0.4 | Managed persistence context support is no longer available for use with the Aries Blueprint container.
```

Note my example is using container-managed JPA.  Seems odd this is actually unsupported, but will try an unmanaged JPA implementation over the weekend.

Comment: Can you post code from `PersonServiceImpl.add()`?

Comment: Confirm your project structure according to this document http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch06.html. According to document hibernate.properties file OR persistence.xml should be in project

Comment: Agreed, and I have the persistence.xml file in the project, but not the hibernate.properties file.  It seems any configuration I can set in hibernate.properties can also be defined in persistence.xml.  So all should be good on this front.  Still unsure what is causing reflection on the Person class to fail.

Comment: are you sure that you are facing this issue while adding `person` to DB. because I have created an small application which is working perfect.

Comment: can you make sure by applying breakpoint at `PersonServiceImpl.add()` and check `person` object what is the value in `name` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deployed the same code listed in this original post to an Apache Karaf 3.0.3 instance, and the code works fine.  The issue is with Apache Karaf 4.0.0 M2, and more specifically with Apache Aries v1.0.4.

As posted earlier, Aries 1.0.4 is generating the following warning upon startup in Karaf 4.0.0 M2

```
2015-06-06 04:17:02,988 | WARN  | FelixStartLevel  | aries                            | 144 - org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint.aries - 1.0.4 | Managed persistence context support is no longer available for use with the Aries Blueprint container.
```

This warning indicates Aries now has an issue with declaring artifacts in the blueprint.xml file.

Christian Schneider has written a post indicating how Aries now uses Annotations for declaring context:
http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/New+design+for+aries+jpa

I have not experimented with these annotations just yet, but will leave it to others to confirm that Aries 1.0.4 (and therefore Karaf 4.0.0) no longer support declaring context in a blueprint.xml file.